# How to avoid "id undefined" in Next.js dynamic route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am going from one page to another with router :

```js
    const goToArticle = (index) => {
      router.push({
        pathname: `/article/${index}`,
      })
    }
```

The page I am going to is named as `[id].js` and is exported as `Article`

And in the article page I am trying to get that index :

```
export async function getStaticPaths({id})  {
  const res = await fetch('myurl');
  const articles = await res.json();
  console.log(params.id);
  return {
      props: {
          article: articles.items[id]
      }
      }
}
```

> Error : ID is undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'undefined' as it is
> undefined.

How to get that index and return array item with that index ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change function redirection as below:

```
const goToArticle = (index) => {
  router.push({
    pathname: `/article/[id]`,
    as: `/article/${index}`,
  })
}
```

please refer document: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: thats only adding query param to route, but isnt fixin id is undefined error

Comment: oh, sorry. Change to { pathname: `/article/[id]`, as: /articles/${index}" }